# Why are my Java GUI Swing applications locked to apparently 60 fps?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, frame-rate

I have 144fps GSYNC monitor and I can see difference when applications locks me to 60 fps. Here is a video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7qQ3T2k-p0&vq=hd1080 (this is recorded with phone with 240 FPS, videos are then slowed down 0.25 so you can see every frame in 60 FPS)

I can "fix" this by adding this piece of code:

```java
        double last_frame = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 144;
        final int FRAME_TIME = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
        while (true) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-last_frame > FRAME_TIME
            ) {
                frame.repaint();
                last_frame = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }else{
                Thread.sleep(1);// ako nema ovoga onda ce procesor stalno raditi
            }
        }
```

but I feel like this solution is hacky and I should actually edit original swing render loop.

Here is minimal INTELLIJ project required to demonstrate bug (however **you would need 144hz capable monitor**) https://dropbox.com/s/jc074ufqkj8r2g7/fpsbug.7z?dl=1 project is just simple GUI Swing with one text field.

MRE code is basically this:

```java
package me.vanjavk;
import javax.swing.*;
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setContentPane(new example().pnl);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private JPanel pnl;
    private JTextField textField1;
}
```

Comment: are you running an animation w/ your program?

Comment: If you could post a [mre] that reproduces the problem, that might help

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no, this is just a simple GUI program as you can see in video, few labels, buttons, textfields. Nothing special.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Here is minimal INTELLIJ project required to demonstrate bug (however you would need 144hz capable monitor) https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc074ufqkj8r2g7/fpsbug.7z?dl=1
 project is just simple GUI Swing with one text field.

Comment: Please post all pertinent code, including your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), here in your question as code-formatted text, not in a link. Thank you.